# Running Spark on top of Slurm

Tags: scala, apache-spark, slurm

How can I run Spark on top of Slurm cluster? I am much interested to define the SparkContext inside my program and set how many nodes I want to use, but if I have to write some bash scripts for it, that would be also okay.

Answer (score 8):

Magpie (https://github.com/llnl/magpie) is a package of shell scripts used for running Big Data applications (such as Spark) on top of traditional HPC clusters (such as those managed by SLURM). It manages much of the complexity of queueing jobs for you, but you may still need to modify the submission scripts to suit your own Spark application - see the file `submission-scripts/script-sbatch/magpie.sbatch-spark` for more information.

Comment: As an interesting side-note, here's an article about LLNL's development of Magpie and the results they obtained on their HPC cluster: http://computation.llnl.gov/research/project-highlights/enhancing-data-intensive-computing-livermore

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Just use Spark's standalone mode side-by-side with whatever Slurm
   does. This means allocating a static subset of resources on the
   target machines to each system.
2. Implement Slurm as a cluster option
   for Spark. This is best for true management and sharing of
   resources, but much harder because of you have to figure out Spark's
   clustering abstractions and implement them correctly. You could
   start by looking at how YARN or Mesos support is implemented.